# '{:08b}' .format(i) Equivalent in Python 2.x

Tags: python, binary, string-formatting

I have a small bit of code in Python 3 -

```
'{:08b}' .format(i)
```

that gives an error in Python 2.x.  Does anyone know the equivalent?

Answer (score 9):

Your original code actually works in Python 2.7. For Python 2.6, you need to introduce a reference to your `format` argument - either an index (`0`):

```
'{0:08b}'.format(i)
```

or a name:

```
'{x:08b}'.format(x=i)  # or:
'{i:08b}'.format(i=i)  # or even:
'{_:08b}'.format(_=i)  # (since you don't care about the name)
```

Strangely enough, this particular quirk doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [documentation about string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) :(

Comment: Well I'll be ... Here I was just assuming it didn't work on python2.7.  Here's the monstrosity I came up with:  `'{:0>8s}' .format(bin(i)[2:])`.  Clearly not worth posting as an answer ... (+1)

Comment: What about `'{0:08b}'.format(i)`?  I think that should work on both python2.x and python3.x without a problem and it's still using positional arguments like the original...

Comment: It indeed does work for both. I've updated my answer to include it as preferred option.

Comment: ... but, and there is always a but ... in Python 2.7, '{:08b}' .format(i), "i" must be an integer, but in Python 3, "i" must be a string.

Comment: @brett I just tested `'{:08b}'.format(42)` in Python 3.3.1 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fun(i):
    print ('{0:08b}'.format(i))
fun(i) # Put any decimal number instead of i in fun(i) like fun(5). The result will be the binary code for number five which is 00000101
```